# Linkedin iOS App in-App browser not allowing to donwload zip files shows unreadable code

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm having an issue with a website I built. If someone click on a post linking to my website, the iOS App opens the site in the in-App browser. When click on a link in the website to download a zip file, the browser attempts to open the file as text and you only see garbled text.

I tested it on the Android app and it works fine there.

Any advice is Welcomed. Do we need to report this as a bug in LinkedIn? Has anyone found anything related to this in the official LinkedIn documentation (I haven't).

Comment: Have you checked that the `Content-Type` Header is correctly set? It is difficult to help without any code/example to follow

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm also having a very similar issue. In my case its pdf downloads that just show as 'garbled text'. Works as expected everywhere apart from via linkedin's in-app browser on ios. (Content Type and Disposition are correct.)

Comment: It seems linkedIn on IOS does not allow downloads. If i set the content-type to "application/octet-stream" it will present a toast message saying "File downloads are not supported". If I set it to "application/pdf" it will render the PDF in browser. Anything else and it will present the raw data as text. I suspect that something similar is happening with your .zip.